# WebGL: obtain canvas coordinates for each vertex

Tags: matrix, webgl, coordinate-transformation

Is it possible to know the canvas coordinates for each vertex in a 3D model already rendered with webgl? 
Can it be done by using a GLSL-script or with pure javascript?

The question points to pick a triangle based on their vertices coordinates.

Comment: Is this an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/)? What are actually trying to do? The answer though is both "yes, of course" and "no, you can't". There is no easy way to know in the general case. You'd have to write an entire WebGL emulator and emulate GLSL so you can run the vertex shaders and see what the output is of your simulated `gl_Position`. It would be really slow and be a ton of work so effectively the answer is "no you can't"

Comment: The purpose is not rendering but performing some sort of facet-pick (as oposite to model/solid pick). If we can know the vertices coordinates (in canvas system), it would be easy to determine what triangle was clicked.

Comment: Btw I am trying to achieve the same by using facet coloring, but cannot use it until I totally eliminate the antialiasing (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438203/webgl-render-antialias/57438237#57438237)

Comment: You should ask a new question, "How to I pick triangles using the GPU?" rather than asking all these unrelated questions

Comment: my question is not unrelated. it is exploring a possible way to pick a triangle. In any case, the intent has been already explained.

Comment: Well then as your question is stated I've already given you an answer.