# WebGL render antialias

Tags: webgl, antialiasing

I am using webgl with javascript. Is there a way to render without antialias? I need every pixel to be of a solid color.

my current fragment shader is very simple:

```
precision mediump float;
varying highp vec3 lighting;

void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(lighting, 1.0);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Based on @Moormanly's answer, I have achieved the following by setting the antialias attribute in the getContext:

Default aliasing:

[image: alias=default]

Antialias = false:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can set attributes when creating a context using the ( optional ) second parameter of the getContext method.
>
> **Code:**
>
> `var context = canvas.getContext('webgl', {antialias: false});`
>
> Check out chapter 5.2 of the [WebGL specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#5.2) for more information.

From [forums.tigsource.com](https://forums.tigsource.com/index.php?topic=40236.0)

Comment: using your suggestion, the image is more jigsawed but not perfectly, there is still some alias perceived. I am using macOS/Safari.

Comment: have a look at the screenshots I have added to the question

Comment: The problem is only with Safari. Chrome works OK. it is something related with Retina, but anyway, gl.ReadPixels() returns flat colors.